# What is the fastest way to xor 2 integers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, performance, xor

Given an array a of n elements, I should replace `a[i]` with `a[i] XOR a[i+1]` and the value of `a[n-1]` with `a[n-1] XOR a[0]` for m number of times. The value of m may reach up to 10^18. What is the fastest and best approach?

```
n, m = gets.chomp.split(" ").map &:to_i
arr = gets.chomp.split(" ")
m -= 1
m.times do
  brr = arr.dup
  i = 0.to_i
  for i in 0..n-2
    brr[i] = (arr[i].to_i ^ arr[i+1].to_i)
  end
  brr[n-1] = (arr[n-1].to_i ^ arr[0].to_i)
  arr = brr.dup
  p arr
  puts ""
end
```

Is there a faster way to calculate the XOR value other than ^ operator?

Comment: Write 10^18 lines of code.

Comment: What does `a[i] ^ a[i+1]` mean when `i` is the last index in the array?  You need to specify the boundary conditions.

Comment: In Ruby, if an array `a` has `n` elements there is no element `a[n]`.  Array indexing starts at zero.

Comment: The fastest way to XOR two integers in ruby is to use XOR operator: `a ^ b`

Comment: is this a project euler problem?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev OP already knew that, judging from the code provided. I'm pretty sure that OP's instructor wants the class to apply mathematical properties of XOR to see a pattern that will emerge without having to do all the iterations.  Dare I say it might be related to `m` modulo `n`?

Comment: @pjs: yeah, it was a subtle hint that question title doesn't match the actual question :)

Answer (score 3):

Stop thinking about it in terms of particular numbers, and consider basic mathematical rules for `^`:

1. x ^ x = 0.
2. x ^ 0 = x.
3. ^ is associative and commutative, so, for instance:

   (x<sub>1</sub> ^ x<sub>2</sub>) ^ (x<sub>3</sub> ^ x<sub>2</sub>) = x<sub>1</sub> ^ (x<sub>2</sub> ^ x<sub>2</sub>) ^ x<sub>3</sub> = x<sub>1</sub> ^ 0 ^ x<sub>3</sub> = x<sub>1</sub> ^ x<sub>3</sub>.

Write out a small array (n = 3 or 4) in terms of x<sub>i</sub>'s rather than actual specific numbers, and apply those rules through a few (m) iterations of your algorithm.  You will see a repeated pattern emerge for m > n.

### ADDENDUM

Once you see the pattern, Ruby's [Array#rotate](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) might be incredibly handy (and provide a very fast solution) for you.